# Combining 3 steps into one SQL script

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm pretty new to SQL, so it sould be rather easy to answer my questions.

Here is what I want to do:

1. Deactivate constraints:

   Deactivate constraints in the database:

   ```
   begin
       for cur in (select fk.owner, fk.constraint_name , fk.table_name 
              from all_constraints fk, all_constraints pk 
              where fk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' and 
                    pk.owner = 'USER1' and
                    fk.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME ) loop
           execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '||cur.owner||'.'||cur.table_name||' MODIFY CONSTRAINT '||cur.constraint_name||' DISABLE';
       end loop;
   end;
   ```
2. Delete from tables:

   ```
   delete from USER_TEST.Table1;                
   delete from USER_TEST.Table2;               
   delete from USER_TEST.Table3;
   ```
3. Reactivate Constraints:

   ```
   begin
     for cur in (select fk.owner, fk.constraint_name , fk.table_name 
                 from all_constraints fk, all_constraints pk 
                 where fk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' and 
                       pk.owner = 'USER1' and
                       fk.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME ) loop
          execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '||cur.owner||'.'||cur.table_name||' MODIFY CONSTRAINT '||cur.constraint_name||' ENABLE NOVALIDATE';
      end loop;
   end;
   ```

Does anyone know how to combine these steps into one `.sql` script so I can run this on Oracle SQLDeveloper? Or maybe a more elegant way to perform the deletion from the tables?

I'd be very thankful

Comment: Take out the last 'end;' from 1. and the first 'begin' from 3 ?

Comment: Be very careful, though - you have the potential risk of being unable to reactivate constraints after 2.

Comment: Thanks!  do you have another way to delete he table contents?

Comment: You could order the deletes so that you delete in the correct order ("children" first, "parents" last). Or declare the FK constraints as "DEFERRABLE" in that case they will be evaluated when you commit, not when you run the `DELETE`

Comment: The issue is not so much the way you are deleting so much as THAT you are deleting.  I suppose you are removing the constraints just to speed things up, but it is easy to imagine a foreign key that cannot be re-enabled after data have been removed...

Comment: i would also fetch the constraints into a local collection (using `bulk collect into`). first, it will save the last duplicate query. second , in case of an exception you could handle each constraint individually according to its status.

Comment: You can define the constraints as deferred, then you don't need to bother about the correct order and the constraints will be evaluated when you commit the `DELETE` transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just about deleting from tables which have foreign keys to each other, you can always delete in constraint order ("children first"). Then you won't have to mess with your constraints at all. Don't forget to commit at the end.

If it is about speed, then you may want to disable constraints and empty the tables via TRUNCATE rather then DELETE. You should however, not delete ALL constraints of the schema, but just the foreign keys of the affected tables which point to another affected table. This will prevent you from shooting into your foot. You can to this without looping, just disable the constraints explicitly. E

So the entire script should look like this

```
Alter Table User_test.Table1 Modify Constraint FK... Disable;
Alter Table User_test.Table2 Modify Constraint FK... Disable;
...

Trunacte Table user_test.Table1;
Trunacte Table user_test.Table2;
...

Alter Table User_test.Table1 Modify Constraint FK... Enable;
Alter Table User_test.Table2 Modify Constraint FK... Enable;
...
```